# How to do backward error analysis of $Ax=b$?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, floating-point

I know the definition of forward error, backward error and condition number. The following is a backward error analysis I think.

Let $A$ be a square matrix of order $n$ and $\hat{x}$ be a approximate solution of $Ax=b$. We want to know the forward error $\|x-\hat{x}\|$, so approximate the condition number $\kappa$ of $A$ and the backward error $\|b-A\hat{x}\|$.

$$\text{Forward error}\leq \text{Condition number}\times\text{Backward error}$$

Suppose that an approximate value of $\kappa$ was obtained and we will approximate the backward error.

Let $fl(A\hat{x})$ be the value of $A\hat{x}$ computed by floating-point arithmetic. Then $\|b-A\hat{x}\|\leq\|b-fl(A\hat{x})\|+\|fl(A\hat{x})-A\hat{x}\|$ and we can know upper bounds for these.

Is the above a backward error analysis?

Comment: The task is somewhat unclear, or perhaps you used the wrong name. Under backwards error analysis it is commonly understood to change the inputs so that exact evaluation gives the numerical output. Meaning that if you have a numerical procedure with $\hat x=solve(A,b)$, then the aim is to find $\tilde A,\tilde b$ close to $A,b$ with $\hat x=\tilde A^{-1}\tilde b$. At the moment you leave $A$ constant in your analysis, which might lead to a larger distance in the replacement $\tilde b$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann How do you find $\tilde{A}, \tilde{b}$?

Comment: I was primarily asking if I have the same understanding of "backward error analysis" as you. It could be that your claim is about something slightly different, but given the same name. The result might also depend on the solver algorithm that is used.